# Two of the same Service instances and stuck on starting/stopping - How to remove one Instance - OnPrem SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, spservices, reporting-services

So we recently updated our SharePoint Farm (6 Servers [2 Web, 2 App, 2 Search]). Everything is working fine beside, SQL Server Repoing Service. We had some problems with getting the settings correct or even starting it.

Currently our Problem is that when looking through the managment shell with Get-SPServiceInstance we have 2 of those instances with 2 different ids. However one is disabled and the other is stuck on Provsioning/Unprovisioning. When we start/stop the other one, it is then stuck on the status and the one that was stucked bevor is then on the Status Disabled.

Q: How can I remove one of the Instances? or How can I force one of the two to start?

Answer (score 0):

Do an IISRESET first, then follow [the article](https://guidesharepoint.wordpress.com/2019/01/02/sharepoint-service-stuck-on-stopping-starting/) to delete the timer job then provison the service again.

If the issue still exists, try following PowerShell to uninstall SSRS, then install it again to compare the result.

```
Install-SPRSService -uninstall
Install-SPRSServiceProxy -uninstall
```